# Deezer android sdk unable to login with Google

Tags: android, deezer

When I run the android-sample app located on github, everything works as expected. However when I try to login with "Sign in with Google" button, nothing happens. There is no output to the logcat either.

Is this feature currently working in the android beta sdk? I am using deezer-sdk-0.11.2.aar